# How do I make complex int16 numbers in octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, short, complextype

In Matlab (my version happens to be R2010b) one can convert a complex double into a complex int16 type as so:

```
>> a = 8.3+4.9j;
>> ai16 = int16(a)
ai16 = 
    8 + 5i
>> whos ai16
Name       Size       Bytes       Class     Attributes
ai16       1x1            4       int16     complex
```

i.e. ai16 is a complex int16 type (equivalent to C++ complex< short > for example).

Octave (ver 4.0.0) does not like this one bit:

```
>> ai16 = int16(a)
error: invalid conversion from complex scalar to int16 scalar
```

I am trying to port some legacy Matlab code to Octave.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get around this in a painless way?  I thought of this:

```
ai16.real = int16(real(a));
ai16.imag = int16(imag(a));
```

but that would propagate a lot of pain through out the code base.  There are many arrays that have been converted from complex double to complex int16. And these arrays are used in many computations.

Comment: the less painful way will probably be to do it with double precision. Does it really need to be int16?

Comment: can you give examples on what many computations are you performing with such complex integers? Because it seems that Matlab does not support complex integer arithmetic. Just try `uint8 (5 + 6j) + uint8 (5 + 6j)` See also [Octave's bug #38959](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?38959)

Comment: It does have to be converted to int16 to communicate with hardware.  But you are right it seems that prior to computation the array is converted to double anyways.  Thanks for the link to the octave bug report.